# Ruby End of Window Size Change

Tags: ruby, terminal, resize, window, size

In ruby, I'm trying to get the window size of the terminal. To do so, I'm using Highline in the following manner:

```
def get_size
  (@cols, @rows) = HighLine::SystemExtensions.terminal_size
end
```

In a main method I have a trap on the window change like so:

```
Signal.trap('SIGWINCH') do
  get_size
  ... do other work
end
```

The difficulty I'm having is I would like to only '... do other work' after the window size change is complete. If I'm dragging and changing the window size, the trap gets called on all my movements. Is there an event or signal I can trap for window size change complete? Or some type of programming methodology I can employ to only initiate my work after the dragging and changing of window size is complete?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to listen for “signal is no more emitting.” A common approach would be to delay a job execution until there is 1 second passed _since last delay_.